# saltstack and common dependencies

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to understand how saltstack means to handle common dependencies.  A trivial example (I have far more complicated ones that motivate the question) is my log directory.  Our services (the ones we install) log to subdirectories of `/var/log/mycompany/`.  This is easy, and in `salt/system/init.sls` we specify the creation of `/var/log/mycompany/`.

Now other modules depend on that so that we don't try to start services before their log directories can be created.  For example, telegraf wants its log directory to exist (or, at least, this was true when I wrote this code), and so I have this:

```
/var/log/jellybooks/telegraf:
  file.directory:
    - user: telegraf
    - group: telegraf
    - mode: 755
    - require:
      - file: /var/log/mycompany
```

This works when calling `state.highstate` but fails if calling `state.apply telegraf`, since even if `/var/log/mycompany` exists, there's no recipe for it.

At its most trivial level, this makes debugging harder.  More subtle effects occasionally annoy.  Surely saltstack must have a pattern for handling this, but I haven't found it.  [This issue](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/12179) sort of addressed it, but it's a bit different.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Salt don't have a `dependency` definition for the state system.
But you can achieve something similar by using `include`

For example

```
# dir.sls
/var/log/mycompany:
  file.directory:
    - user: mycompany

# another.sls
include:
- dir

/var/log/jellybooks/telegraf:
  file.directory:
    - user: telegraf
    - group: telegraf
    - mode: 755
    - require:
      - file: /var/log/mycompany
```

When you call `state.highstate`, it will retrieve everything need to run then execute it. So it probably reads `salt/system/init.sls` and understand that for later use.
On the other hand, `state.apply telegraf` will only read and execute `telegraf.sls`

Ref:

- Simple example: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/config/include.html
- Highstate: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/highstate.html
- State tutorial with include: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/states_pt3.html

Comment: Thanks, and true, but this doesn't address the core issue, which is testing individual sls and debugging.  Having to run highstate and puzzle through why an issue occurs can be quite tricky.  It's nice to be able to pare it down.  But if paring down means I lose dependencies, it's less useful.

Comment: @jma I don't see it as losing dependencies. It's just another way to implement it.
I usually check [salt-formulas](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas) for reference how to write state file.
If you really want to keep your current work, you may try to run the test state + the dependencies states
`salt test-minion state.sls depend1,depend2,main`